# How to find intersections of sine and cosine functions with $X$ axis

Tags: geometry, functions, trigonometry

I've been struggling with this question for a few days, because I've been able to find the said intersections, but based on suppositions, rather than on mathematical process.

For example, if I have the sine function: $F(x) = \sin(\pi x)$:

Since the period is ${2\pi\over \pi} = 2$, and that means that a whole cycle occurs between $(0,0)$ and $(2,0)$, I suppose that in such cycle, it would also touch $(1,0)$ since that would be "half the cycle".

From the aforementioned I suppose that intersections with $X$ axis are 
$(n, 0)$ in which $\{n | n \in Z\}$.

So, for this case, the x intersections seem to be half the period:
${{2\pi\over \pi}\over 2} = 1$ and the result would be the difference between each intersection point.

However, all what is said above is based on pure supposition, so it might just work for this particular case, or, at least, for cos/sin functions with amplitude $1$; but I also have functions such as $F(x) = 10\cos({x\over 2})$ or $F(x) = 3\sin(-5x)$, and I'm pretty sure that they have a whole different process, and I don't know how to find their intersections.

What I'm asking for, then, is a general way for finding the intersections of a sine and cosine function with $X$ axis.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The sine and cosine can be defined from the properties of a rectangular triangle.

[image: from nl wikipedia]
([Source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ciclo.png))

From this it is obvious for which angle these functions vanish.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I already came up with my own method... maybe it exists already, but I like to deduce this kinda' things my self, so I never forget'em.

So let's say we have this function: $F(x) = 10\cos({x\over 2}).$

The function insterects x axis when $y=0$, so $10\cos({x\over 2})= 0$

In order to get rid of that $10$: ${10\cos({x\over 2})\over 10} = {0\over10}$

Now, all we have is $\cos({x\over 2}) = 0$, so at this point it gets really easy because all we have to do is:

${x\over 2} = \cos^{-1}(0)$

Now to find which values of $\hat x$  $\cos(\hat x)=0$.

${x\over 2} = \{ {\pi\over 2} , {3\pi\over 2}, {5\pi\over 2},\dots {(2n+1)\pi\over 2}\}$

This tells us that : ${x\over 2} ={(2n+1)\pi\over 2}$

Then, all we have to do is get rid of that 1/2 beside x, by dividing it on the other side of the equation:

$x ={{(2n+1)\pi/ 2} \over {1/2}}$

And that equals

$x = (2n+1)\pi$

$\therefore$ the values of $x$, when $y = 0$, for $y=F(x) = 10\cos({x\over 2})$ are:

$( (2n+1)\pi , 0 )\ \  \{n \in Z\}$

This has worked for all my other functions, so I guess that this method has been already demonstrated for all possible cases, if someone could tell me where can I find such demonstration, that'd really kind.

Thanks.

Comment: Consider using Mathjax to format your equations. Here is a tutorial: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference